# How to set origin point in center?

Tags: origin

Can't believe I'm asking this question right now, but how do I set my origin point to the center of my plane? I'm trying to apply a mirror modifier but the center of origin is throwing everything off track. I have the shrink-wrap modifier on if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Set my 3D cursor to center, set origin point to 3D cursor, apply the shrink wrap, set the target to the character, then applied the mirror modifier.